# is there a way to make this query load faster

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, query-optimization, laravel-query-builder

I have this query in laravel

```
$visitors = Visitor::select('visitors.sex', 'event_visitor.event_id', DB::raw('count(*) as num_visits'))
    ->join('event_visitor', 'visitors.id', '=', 'event_visitor.visitor_id')
    ->whereIn('event_visitor.event_id', $events_id->take(10))
    ->groupBy('visitors.sex', 'event_visitor.event_id')
    ->get();
```

it shows the visitor's gender and counts in the last 10 events like this

```
sex   event_id num_visits   
female  1       10056
male    1        9965
female  2        9894
male    2        9894
```

right now my visitors table size is 600K, and the events table is 20 so on each event there is 30K visitor attached and the query takes 2s to load the data

this is the query in MySQL form

```
select visitors.sex,
       event_visitor.event_id,
       count(*) as num_visits 
from visitors 
inner join event_visitor on visitors.id = event_visitor.visitor_id 
where event_visitor.event_id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) 
and visitors.deleted_at is null 
group by visitors.sex, event_visitor.event_id
```

and this is what the explain shows

[image: explain]

Comment: Have you added indexes to your db tables ?

Comment: If you prefix your current query by the work `explain`, you can see which keys mysql follows. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: @GertB. yes, I have indexed the IDs and the genders...

Comment: It looks like you have the right indexes, and the EXPLAIN shows that it considered using the index on `event_id`, but decided it didn't give enough benefit, so it just used a table-scan. Based on your estimates of 30K rows per event, the query will examine 50% of the rows in the table even using the index, so it's not surprising that the optimizer chooses not to use it. I expect it will use the index only if you select 4 or fewer events.

Comment: How many visitors went to those 10 events?  60K?  30K?  Something much smaller?

Comment: every event has 30K visitors